# Cross fading between elements

Tags: jquery

What I need help with is pretty straight forward and I hope you can help me with it.

What I have is a jcarousel scrolling thumbnail carousel that has a slide show added to it.
When you click on one of the scrolling thumbnails in the scroller it displays the image larger to the right. I have the script working perfectly that's not a problem. What I need help with is that I would like to add a cross fade transition to the images being displayed to the right once the thumbnail has been clicked. I have attached a link to the original code I worked from and my own code on my page.
Original code can be found here: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/jcarousel/index.html

I think this can be done with css and jquery with the li elements of the carousel scroller and the main slide element. I'm just not sure and any help would be appreciated pointing me in the right direction. Here is my code on my webpage.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jcarousel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skin.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //jCarousel Plugin
        $('#carousel').jcarousel({
            vertical: true,
            scroll: 1,
            auto: false,
            visible: 4,
            wrap: 'last',
            initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
        });

    //Front page Carousel - Initial Setup
    $('div#slideshow-carousel a img').css({'opacity': '0.5'});
    $('div#slideshow-carousel a img:first').css({'opacity': '1.0'});
    $('div#slideshow-carousel li a:first').append('<span class="arrow"></span>')


    //Combine jCarousel with Image Display
    $('div#slideshow-carousel li a').hover(
        function () {

            if (!$(this).has('span').length) {
                $('div#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({'opacity': '0.5'});
                $(this).stop(true, true).children('img').css({'opacity': '1.0'});
            }       
        },
        function () {

            $('div#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({'opacity': '0.5'});
            $('div#slideshow-carousel li a').each(function () {

                if ($(this).has('span').length) $(this).children('img').css({'opacity': '1.0'});

            });

        }
    ).click(function () {

            $('span.arrow').remove();        
        $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
        $('div#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active');        
        $('div#slideshow-main li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');   

        return false;
    });


});


//Carousel Tweaking

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
}

    </script>


<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/* Slide Show */
body {
    font-family:arial;  
}

img {
    border:0;
}

#slideshow-main {
    width:429px; 
    float:; 
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-left:120px;
}

#slideshow-main ul {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:429px;
}

#slideshow-main li {
    width:429px; 
    height:290px; 
    display:none;
    position:relative;
}

#slideshow-main li.active {
    display:block !important;
}


#slideshow-main li span.content {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0; left:0;
    display:block; 
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    z-index:1000;
}

#slideshow-main li span.content h1 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:0 10px;;
    color:#000000;
}

#slideshow-main li span.content p {
    font-size:11px;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:0 10px;;
    color:#000000;
}

#slideshow-carousel {
    float:left; 
    width:95px;
    position:relative
}

#slideshow-carousel ul {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#slideshow-carousel li {
    background:#fff; 
    height:97px; 
    position:relative
}

#slideshow-carousel li .arrow {
    left:3px; 
    top:28px; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:20px; 
    height:40px; 
    background:url(images/arrow_white.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    display:block;
}

#slideshow-carousel li a {
    background:#000; 
    display:block; 
    width:95px; 
    height:95px;
}


#slideshow-carousel .active {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    -moz-opacity:1.0; 
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0; 
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#slideshow-carousel .faded {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    -moz-opacity:0.5; 
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
    opacity: 0.5;
}


    </style>



</head>

<body>

    <div id="welcomeHero">

        <div id="slideshow-main">
            <ul>
                <li class="p1 active">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv01.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 1</h1><p>Photo vv01.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="p2">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv02.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 2</h1><p>Photo vv02.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="p3">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv03.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 3</h1><p>Photo vv03.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="p4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv04.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 4</h1><p>Photo vv04.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="p5">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv05.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 5</h1><p>Photo vv05.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="p6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv06.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 6</h1><p>Photo vv06.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="p7">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/vv07.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                        <span class="opacity"></span>
                        <span class="content"><h1>Title 7</h1><p>Photo vv07.</p></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>

        <div id="slideshow-carousel" style="margin-top: -280px; position: absolute;">               
              <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
                <li><a href="#" rel="p1"><img src="images/vv01.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="p2"><img src="images/vv02.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="p3"><img src="images/vv03.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="p4"><img src="images/vv04.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="p5"><img src="images/vv05.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="p6"><img src="images/vv06.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="p7"><img src="images/vv07.jpg" width="95" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: Thank you mentioning it. I should have done it to begin with. Here is the fiddle of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/xvyu58de/

Answer (score 0):

im thinking quick way to do that is by css.
try something like this:

```
#slideshow-main li a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#slideshow-main li.active a {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

not sure if it's working or not havent checked it but hope you got the idea ;)

yes youre right it's not working.
i made some adjustment on css (only), can you please have them check in your codes?

```
#slideshow-main ul {
    height: 290px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 429px;
}


#slideshow-main li {
    display: inherit;
    height: 290px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 429px;
}

#slideshow-main li.active {
    /* display: block!important; */
}

#slideshow-main li a {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#slideshow-main li.active a {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That did not seem to make any difference. I have tried other css with no success. I might need js also to do this. I'm not sure?

Comment: yes it was not working sorry. but i gave you an edit which i hope (again) it will be working..and i hope the absolute position using in the slideshow doesnt bother you

Comment: dont give up on css3 ;)

Comment: Your Absolutely a GENIUS!!! Works absolutely PERFECT!.... Thank you so very much. I was hoping to solve this issue with just css. May you and your family be truly blessed!